# Share textview doesn't work with Facebook apps

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, textview, share

I have a simple textview and i want it to be shared via social especially Facebook and Facebook messanger.

I tried this code but i got just whatsapp,mail and messaging working. With Facebook there are not errors, if i press the Facebook icon the only think i get is a empty post, the same happened with messenger.

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.action_share:         
            Intent intent2=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent2.setType("text/plain");
            intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"'"+ random + "'" + "\n"+"By example"); //random is the textview
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent2, "Share via"));
            break;

            case R.id.randombut:
                 Frasi();
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
            break;

     }
    return true;
}
```

Now i read a lots of topics about and some of them said that this is a Facebook issue, basically Facebook doesn't allow communication by intent. But i read as well that starting with 2012 it should be resolved. 
My question is: is there a way to do that or is still impossible?

Comment: This is by design. You are not allowed to prefill message

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it only works when you use a link as the text to be shared. Normal text is ignored, but links are displayed.

Comment: so, how can i do to something like if you press Facebook share the link, anyway share the textview

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Facebook SDK if you want to share something on the wall of facebook, that's why you get an empty field when you click on facebook

The normal share allows you to post ONLY link and no text ecc...

look at the official page of facebook sdk for android [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share)